# Change one cell in a python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a python dataframe in which a column is named `Country` ; in this column, in a certain row (I don't know which one), the cell contains the name *Italy*. In the same column, in another row (I don't know where), the cell contains the name *San Marino*. I want just to change the name *San Marino* by the name *Italy* (so that I will have two  *Italy* in the column `Country`).

This is surely a basic question, but well, I don't know how to do this simple thing in Python... Could you help me with the code to use?

Comment: `dataframe`? is it a `pandas` question?

Comment: Yes. I used `import pandas as pd`, then `data = pd.read_csv(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to replace the occurrences of `San Marino` with `Italy`.

Use:

```
df["Country"] = df["Country"].str.replace("San Marino", "Italy")
```

To create copy of original `df`:

```
df_copy = df.copy()
df_copy["Country"] = df_copy["Country"].str.replace("San Marino", "Italy")
```

Comment: @Andrew If this answered your question you may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a `pandas.DataFrame` and your DataFrame is called `df`, you can use

```py
df.loc[df['Country'] == 'San Marino', 'Country'] = 'Italy'
```

---

Example:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Italy', 'Norway', 'San Marino']})
>>> print(df)
      Country
0       Italy
1      Norway
2  San Marino

>>> df.loc[df['Country'] == 'San Marino', 'Country'] = 'Italy'
>>> print(df)
  Country
0   Italy
1  Norway
2   Italy
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df["Country"][df.Country == 'San Marino'] = 'Italy'
```

Comment: Thanks all ! Would it be possible to create a **new** dataframe when making the change (as the solutions given above modify the existing data frame...)